# Why is my EF CodeFirst configuration not using the specified foreign key property?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following model:

```
public class Hotfix
{
    public int? released_version { get; set; }
    public virtual ReleaseVersion ReleasedVersion { get; set; }
}
```

In my mapping class (which is correctly being looked at) I have:

```
            this.Property(t => t.released_version).HasColumnName("released_version");
        this.HasOptional(t => t.ReleasedVersion)
            .WithMany(t => t.ReleaseVersionForHotfix)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.released_version);
```

However, when I perform a query such as `_context.Hotfixes.ToList()` I get the exception `Invalid column name 'ReleaseVersion_id'.`.

Why is it looking for a `ReleaseVersion_id` column when it's being told the column should be mapped to `released_version`?

This is using CodeFirst on an existing database

Comment: Are you sure you are applying the configuration of `Hotfix` class? This snippet looks correct.

Comment: Yes.  My `DBContext.OnModelCreating()` is calling `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new hotfixMap())`, which is the mapping configuration class the 2nd snippet is from

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka incase you don't notice my update (and are interested), I found the bug that is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out, and apparently it was due to some code not shown.  There seems to be a bug in EF's fluent mapping when extra properties exist that are not mapped.  I should have shown the `ReleaseVersion` structure which looks like:

```
public class ReleaseVersion
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Hotfix> CurrentVersionForHotfix { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hotfix> ReleaseVersionForHotfix { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hotfix> hotfixes2 { get; set; }
}
```

What's significant is the extra `hotfixes2` property.  This property was created by the EF 4.1 CodeFirst power tools, but I didn't remove it because I wanted to get everything working first.

Anyways, the `hotfixes2` property had no relationship mapping in the hotfix EF configuration mapping class but for some reason this one extra property was causing the whole hotfix configuration to be disgarded.  Simply removing the `hotfixes2` property from the `ReleaseVersion` POCO caused my application to correctly work without errors.